# Possible number of line segments in a square grid

Tags: combinatorics

My problem is:

> "How many possible line segments can be formed from an $n \times n$ square grid?"

For example by manual counting, if $n = 1$, then the number of line segments $= 0$; if $n = 2$, then the number of line segments $= 6$; and if $n = 3$, then the number of line segments $= 36$. All I can think of is the formula for finding all possible line segments where all points are noncollinear, that is $\frac{n(n -1)}{2}$, but how about a square grid whose intersection of horizontal and vertical line forms a point? How many possible line segments can be formed from such square?

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I do not follow.  In the $3 \times 3$ case, you have already counted line segments that cross through the center point.

Comment: No sir, i only count line segments defined by any 2 points on the square grid...but line segments that starts from opposite ends of the square that cross the center is not counted...

Comment: I only get 28 for 3 points across

Comment: I got 28 by not counting those line segments crossing another point/s I misunderstood... so if p = 1, l = 0, p = 2, l = 6, if p = 3 l = 28... is there any pattern evident? Im suck at combinatorics thats why I tried manual counting then derive formula algebraically...